# Which Laptop should I buy as a CS student?

Tags: laptop

I recently got in a CS program. It will be my first laptop, so don't know much about them. Please recommend me which one should I get?

```
Rating: 5.1 Windows Experience Index
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @1.6GHz 2.30GHz
System type: 64-bit Operating System
Pen or Touch: No Pen or Touch Input is available for this Display.
Computer name: Dell-PC
Workgroup: WORKGROUP

Has number key pad.
```

or

```
Processor: Intel(R)Core(TM)i5 CPU M 520 @ 2.40GHz 2.40 GHz
Installed RAM: 4.00 GB (3.86 GB usable)
System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch: Touch support with 2 touch points.

No number keypad.
```

Comment: There is not enough information to compare these laptops and make a recommendation. What software or programming languages will your school require you to run? How much RAM does the first laptop have? Which operating systems do these laptops come with? What kind of battery life do you need (and what batteries do these laptops have anyways?) What are the brands and model numbers for these laptops?

Answer (score 1):

If these two are really your only options: the first one.
The second option is extremely outdated. Judging by the CPU model, it is about 10 years old. The first one is not exactly recent either, but since I have one with a similar CPU, I can say with confidence that it is sufficient for basic computing needs.

But as was pointed out in a comment, there is more to laptops than the CPU model. If you could refine your question with at least a model name of the laptop, judging its suitability for a CS student would be easier.